# utime csv file gives double backslash

Tags: python

i have this code right now:

```
import os
import time
import datetime
import csv

year = 2017
month = 12
day = 5
hour = 19
minute = 50
second = 0

date = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=minute, second=second)
modTime = time.mktime(date.timetuple())
with open('Book1.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader:
         rows = ''.join(row)

         os.utime(rows, (modTime, modTime))


print("done")
```

when i print rows it works fine and prints `c:\test` for example

when i run utime it says it cant find `c:\\test` which makes sense.

in the csv file it just says `C:\`

how can i solve it so it only makes one backslash.

Comment: What does Books.csv look like? can you provide a sample with a couple of lines?

Comment: Just one colum column A first line in c:\test\test.txt 2nd lime c:\test\testing.txt 3rd line c:\finance\invoice.xlsx

Comment: Your code does not run. It says:     os.utime(rows, (modTime, modTime))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Does this code run for you?

Comment: Why are you reading book1.csv if it is a file with just 1 column? If that the case then it's not really a csv file. It just a text file. I suggest you simplify your example. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why are you calling `os.utime` at all here; what are you hoping to accomplish? Try to remove the CSV reading and just concentrate on operating on a single static file; see also the [help] guidance for writing a [mcve].

Comment: I have 10000 lines of each line is a path with a file. With utime i change the last modified date. I need to do that for all those files

Comment: Yes, but making your Stack Overflow question stand on its own makes it easier for us to help you. If we have to guess what your data looks like or create auxiliary files based on an informal prose description, many people who could otherwise help won't bother. Focusing your question on exactly one problem also makes it more likely to be helpful for future visitors, which is ultimately what we are looking for in questions.

Comment: Anyway, this looks suspiciously like the common FAQ "I see two backslashes but the actual string only contains one". In some contexts, Python will print the `repr()` of a problematic string which causes backslashes to be doubled, among other things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do backslashes appear twice?](/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)

Answer (score 0):

First import path from os

```
from os import path
```

Then use path to split the rows string

```
result = path.split(rows)
```

Set the os.chdir with the first part of the path.split result[0]

```
os.chdir(result[0])
```

Finally os.utime the file in the chdir with the file name in result[1]

```
os.utime(result[1], (modTime, modTime))
```

This is the final code

```
import os
import time
import datetime
import csv
from os import path

year = 2017
month = 12
day = 5
hour = 19
minute = 50
second = 0

date = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=minute, 
second=second)
modTime = time.mktime(date.timetuple())
with open('Book1.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
 spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
 for row in spamreader:
     rows = ''.join(row)
     result = path.split(rows)
     os.chdir(result[0])
     os.utime(result[1], (modTime, modTime))



print("done")
```

Comment: with this code it still does double backslash and it removes the filename.

Comment: This worked fine in my environment and updated all the file times correctly. What python are you using?

Comment: i use python version 3.6 if for example the file is c:\test\test.txt it inly shows c:\test

Comment: can you post your updated code for the os.utime line as a comment please?

Comment: Splitting the path and going `chdir` on the path component only complicates this IMHO. Why don't you simply pass the full path to `os.utime`?

Comment: from https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Whether a directory can be given for path depends on whether the operating system implements directories as files (for example, Windows does not).

I have to split and only use filename with os.utime